# node modules fail to start on edge

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Currently none of my node.js modules work on iot edge. They fail to connect to edge hub.
The log below is from a module that does nothing, just created with VSC and uploaded to a fresh iot edge.

Please advise.

```
[UnauthorizedError: mqtt.js returned Failure on first connection (Not authorized): getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 120101100701 error] {​​​​​​  transportError: Error: Failure on first connection (Not authorized): getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 120101100701
      at /app/node_modules/azure-iot-device-mqtt/dist/mqtt.js:235:104
      at constructor._onEnter (/app/node_modules/azure-iot-mqtt-base/dist/mqtt_base.js:208:29)
      at constructor.transition (/app/node_modules/machina/lib/machina.js:653:28)
      at constructor.Fsm.<computed> [as transition] (/app/node_modules/machina/lib/machina.js:466:63)
      at /app/node_modules/azure-iot-mqtt-base/dist/mqtt_base.js:287:40
      at /app/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:827:11
      at Store.close (/app/node_modules/mqtt/lib/store.js:124:5)
      at /app/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:821:26
      at Store.close (/app/node_modules/mqtt/lib/store.js:124:5)
      at MqttClient.closeStores (/app/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:820:24)
}​​​​​​
```

Comment: Is your edgeHub running? Do any of the logs in edgeAgent or edgeHub indicate what's going on?

Comment: Yes edgeHub and edgeAgent are running, without any errors.

Comment: With the info in your question, I can't reproduce the error. I just installed Azure IoT Edge and created a Node.js module, pushed it to ACR and it's running fine. Please check you have the latest version of everything and include any extra info you might have.